# How to move changes as uncommitted from one branch to another on Git

Tags: git

I want to move all changes that are in a branch relative to master to another branch.

I don't want them as commits just as changes so that i can modify them and remove some of the changes and commit as one. I don't want to retain the old committed history.

I tried git format-patch master --stdout > mypatch.path
and git apply

but that applies as commits which i can't modify after that.

Comment: why not use git stash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, one way would be to start with your first branch:

```
git checkout branch1
```

Create a new branch from there:

```
git checkout -b branch2
```

Reset back to master, which will remove any commits that were made on `branch1`, but leave the changes as unstaged:

```
git reset master
```

You can then modify the files further and commit them as one commit.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this to move the changes from branch1 to branch2:

```
git checkout branch2

git merge --squash branch1
```

No commit has been created or "copied" between the branches. The changes can be modified before committing if need be.